# Is horse meat supposed to be chewy?

Tags: meat, texture

I just had horse meat for the first time and found it rather chewy.  When asked what I thought of it, I said I found it a bit chewy.  I then got a new portion, which was just as chewy.  Is this simply how it is supposed to be?  The waiter suggested as much, but I am skeptical.

Comment: It’s a bit like asking if beef should be chewy. What cut was it, how was it cooked, for how long… If you flash fry shin, sure, similarly if you fry a sirloin for 15 mins…

Comment: @Tetsujin, I don't know.  but, as I said, the waiter implied that this is just how horse meat in general is.

Comment: When I read this question, I immediately thought "Dwight Schrute?"

Comment: It wouldn't be surprising since horses tend to get around a lot more than cows do.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the horse meat.  The Japanese make [horse meat sashimi](https://taiken.co/single/basashi-horse-meat-sashimi/), which as you might expect is quite tender.